# Paperclip: saving both to local server and rackspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to save one picture model to local server, and other model to rackspace. 
Now my paperclip config looks like :

```
config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config/cloudfiles.yml'))

  provider = {
      :provider           => "Rackspace",
      :rackspace_username => config['username'],
      :rackspace_api_key  => config['api_key'],
      :persistent         => false
  }

  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage]         = :fog
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_credentials] = provider
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_directory]   = config["container_#{Rails.env}"]
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_host]        = config["cdn_#{Rails.env}"]
```

and it works with rackspace perfectly. But how can I upgrade this code to allow one of picture's model save pics to local folder, not rackspace ?